# PostGIS MakeLine issue

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, linestring, st-makeline

I am using GPS coordinates and I am trying to create lines (routes) from lon,lat.
I create a geography column from my point and then I create the line as following:

ST_MakeLine(point_geom order by timestamp asc)

Although I have an issue on -180, 180 producing the following:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input.
Actually I solved it using the following :

```sql
select 
*, 
CASE 
  WHEN ST_Intersects(
        line::geography, 
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(180 -90, 180 0, 180 90)',4326)::geography
     ) = True 
  THEN ST_Shift_Longitude(line) 
  ELSE line END AS newLine 
FROM tableName
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ST_ShiftLongitude()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Shift_Longitude.html) to fix this:

> Reads every point/vertex in every component of every feature in a geometry, and if the longitude coordinate is <0, adds 360 to it. The result would be a 0-360 version of the data to be plotted in a 180 centric map

```
ST_ShiftLongitude(ST_MakeLine(...))
```

Note, that this will fix issues on 180° Line, but will introduce the very same issue on the 0° line. If you have geometries that cross 0 **and** 180 degree line, it does not work.

---

I use something like this to determine if my geometry crosses the dateline:

```
abs(ST_XMin(geometry)-ST_XMax(geometry)) > 180
```

So, I can use this:

```sql
CASE
WHEN
    abs(ST_XMin(geometry)-ST_XMax(geometry)) > 180
THEN
    ST_Shift_Longitude(geometry)
ELSE
    geometry
END as geom
```

This works for any kind of geometry. But Same issue here, works only if you have no Geometries that are really more than 180° wide.

Comment: thanks for this, although a proper solution would be to solve this issue even there are point  crossing 0 and 180

Comment: Sure, but unfortunately I have no better solution and afaik there is no automated solution that may fix this, because you just cannot determine how a geometry is intended to be.